# Size a UIView to discrete values using AutoLayout

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, ios-autolayout

The short version goes like this: **I need my UIView to have a width of 50 if there is enough room, or 0 if there isn't.** How can I do this?

---

Now for the long version:

I have a UIView with an icon followed by a label, ideally the view would always look like `|-icon-label-|`

However sometimes the label is too long and something has to give. Instead of resizing / truncating the text or resizing the icon, I need the icon to disappear completely (for example by setting its size to zero).

I was hoping I could achieve this by:

1. Setting the horizontal compression resistance for the icon to a value lower than standard (say 700 instead)
2. Setting an optional high priority on the icon's width constraint (say width=50, priority=900)
3. Setting a lower priority on the icon's width constraint (width=0, priority=800)

With this setup I was hoping that constraint #2 would break as the label got longer, and that constraint #3 would be used as a suitable fallback. However that's not how autolayout works apparently: the icon view is simply resized (shrunk) a little bit, but does not entirely disappear. In other word. constraint #3 is simply ignored.

There has to be a reasonable way to do this? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short: You will have to programmatically change the width for autolayout based on the width of the label.

A bit longer version:

Set just one constraint on the `icon`'s width and keep a reference to it:

```
let iconWidthConstraint = icon.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
iconWidthConstraint.isActive = true
```

And then, when you retrieve the text and set it to the label, you'll have to detect if the `icon` needs to be hidden, and if yes, just change its constant to zero. So something like:

```
label.text = yourText
if label.intrinsicContentSize.width + 50 < containerView.bounds.width {
    iconWidthConstraint.constant = 50
} else {
    iconWidthConstraint.constant = 0
}
```

Here I assume that `containerView` is the superview of the `label` and `icon`, and that it was already put into view hierarchy and laid out (at this point we have to know `containerView.bounds`).

Comment: Thanks! I hoping for something purely AutoLayout solution because the code gets a bit complicated when dealing with a variable size container + attributed text. But at the end of the day, it's the only solution I have found to be working.